# How to Import rootca.cer, subca.cer and certificate.crt into jks

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I got three files from my partner which api i want to use. I have generated a CSR using IIS and send them, they gave me rootca.cer, subca.cer and certificate.crt. Now i want to develop a program using all of these in java (Spring Boot). This is my very new job and i did not do anything like this before. So i want help from expert.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. -- Create keystore.jks:

$ keytool -genkey -alias alias -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048

### 2. -- Import .pfx inot keystore:

$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore privateKey3.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

### 3. -- Import rootca.cer inot keystore:

$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias alias -file root.cer -keystore keystore.jks

### 4. -- Import subca.cer inot keystore:

$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias aliassubca -file subca.cer -keystore keystore.jks

### 5. -- Import certificate.crt inot keystore:

$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias alias -file certificate.crt -keystore keystore.jks

### 6. -- Check keystore:

$ keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks